# Python Scraping From Html Code

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am stuck with a scraping problem:

So I have this html code.. and I need to get the value of the telephone number

```
<body>
    <p class="tel">telephone :</p>
    <p class="val">+123456789</p>
    <p class="fax">Fax :</p>
    <p class="val">+33 3 86 32 42 91</p>
    <p class="email">Email :</p>
    <p class="valeur">my@email.com</p>
</body>
```

How can I get the telephone number using python? I tried using bs4 but i don't know how to find the second `<p>` element from the element with class `tel`.

Comment: Can you share the code that you have made an attempt with?

Comment: i tryed some garbage code .. i think it is humiliating to paste that code. thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate the telephone "label" and get the [next sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
soup.find("p", class_="tel").find_next_sibling("p", class_="val").get_text()
```